# Mutlimedia Keys on Ubuntu 20.04 with Spotify

Tags: keyboard, spotify, media-buttons

So I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04, and wanted to get my Spotify set up. My problem is that the Pause/Play, Next and Previous keys are not being picked up when I try to bind them in the Keyboard Shortcuts section. I've tested with `xev` and it seems to be picking them up, although I can't seem to differentiate between them. The Pause/Play button can control YouTube videos embedded in Discord (I have them disabled in Firefox) but cannot be bound to the `playerctl` commands. Gsettings shows they are bound to `['']`, but that doesn't seem to help me.

Edit: There were Keyboard Shorcut mappings for Audio things, and the keys were good for that, just not custom ones for whatever reason. They still don't work with spotify for whatever reason, which is annoying

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue that people have with Spotify. Fortunately, there is a solution that works 95% of the time.

Follow these steps:

1. Get [Spotify Gnome Integration](https://github.com/jreese/spotify-gnome) from GitHub. This can be downloaded as a Zip file if you don't use Git.
2. (If you downloaded the Zip) Extract the archive.
3. (From the Terminal) Change to the directory that was created when extracting the Gnome integration files, for example:
   `cd ~/Downloads/spotify-gnome`
4. Copy some files using the following command:
   `sudo install bin/spotify /usr/local/bin/`

Note:

For this to work, you will need `python-dbus` on your computer. If you don't have this (or if you can't start Spotify anymore), it can be installed like this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dbus
```

Restart Spotify. The media buttons should now work correctly.

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm getting errors like [this](https://hastebin.com/umefuqefev.sql), and "Didn't get expected metadata" when run from the terminal. The media keys aren't working still, no clue why.

Answer (score 0):

The plasma-browser-integration package helped me with this problem.

```
sudo apt-get install plasma-browser-integration
```